# Date filter issues to include selected from and to date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, linq, logic

I have the following logic which filter date and time between two dates.

```
 this.downloadData = this.downloadData.filter(
      m => new Date(m.LogTime) >= new Date(localStorage.getItem('fromDate')) && new Date(m.LogTime) <= new Date(localStorage.getItem('toDate'))
      );
```

But it will filter selected from and to dates, it will filter from next day of from date and one day before of to date.

I want to include selected from and to dates as well in the results. How should i change the logic for this?

```
Eg:

DateTime array   

2001-12-21 21:00
2001-12-22 21:00
2001-12-23 21:00
2001-12-24 21:00
2001-12-25 21:00
```

If i filter for fromdate  2001-12-21 21:00 and toDate 2001-12-25 21:00

```
Current result

2001-12-21 21:00
2001-12-22 21:00
2001-12-23 21:00
2001-12-24 21:00
2001-12-25 21:00 

Expected result


2001-12-22 21:00
2001-12-23 21:00
2001-12-24 21:00
```

Comment: Are you still facing issues with this?

Comment: yes..i have not yet tried the below code..need to deploy and test as there is not data local

Answer (score 0):

Check below logic and let me know

Converted date to milliseconds and verifying the difference between given date and from date , given date and to date.

```
  var fromDate = Date.parse(localStorage.fromDate); // parse to date object
  var toDate = Date.parse(localStorage.toDate);

  this.downloadData = this.downloadData.filter(
          m => fromDate-Date.parse(m.LogTime)<=0 && Date.parse(m.LogTime)-toDate<=0
          );
```

Let me know if its helpful